# document.createElement is not working in ipad and iphone

Tags: javascript

I have got struct with creating an element in javascript.

```
var newObj = newObj || [];
(function () {
    for (var c = [], r = function (c) {
            return function () {
                newObj.push([c].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)))
            }
        }, a = 0; a < c.length; a++) newObj[c[a]] = r(c[a])
})(), newObj.load = function (c, r) {

    var a = document.createElement("script"),
        a.type = "text/javascript",
        a.src = "https" //XXXXX/dyncamicscript.js";
    var e = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    e.parentNode.insertBefore(a, e);
}, newObj.load("someName");
```

Here I am trying to create a script element which is a CDN link, and I kept an alert in the targeted script file in window.load function.

It is working (it is showing an alert from targeted script file) as expected in desktops and android mobiles but not working (it doesn't show the alert) in Ipad and iPhone.

Here is my script source file 
dyncamicscript.js file

```
window.onload = function (params) {
    alert('loaded');
}
```

Could you please let me know if I missed anything, 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];` try changing that to 'body' or 'head' and append it to there

Comment: did you try to put an alert outside of the onload event ?

Comment: _“but not working (it doesn't show the alert) in Ipad and iPhone”_ - how do you draw the conclusion that creating the element was what is not working from _that_ then? Probably rather an issue of trying to assign a window load event handler at that point in time. I don’t think trying to do that from within an external script that gets loaded dynamically this way, is a good idea to begin with, that is screaming for possible timing issues.

Comment: Alert is not working even I put an alert outside of the onload event, Any other suggestions ?